# "Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist" error trying to connect from React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Chrome extension launches the app in a separate window from the domain "http://localhost:3000" . The domain uses the  app React.

My React App:

**React:**

```
componentDidMount() {
  let connectApp = chrome.runtime.connect(
    "ID My Chrome Extension",
      {
        name: "test",
      }
    );

    connectApp.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
      console.log(msg);
    });

    connectApp.onDisconnect.addListener((obj) => {
      console.log("disconnected port", obj);
    });
}
```

Chrome Extantion:

**background.js**

```
function sendInfoProspectWithDom(data) {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
      text: "create-new-propsect"
  });
}

chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (obj) {
  console.log("onConnect");
});
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "description": "test Description",
  "browser_action": {},
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://mail.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "externally_connectable": {
    "ids": ["*"],
    "matches": [
      "https://localhost:3000/*",
      "http://localhost:3000/*"
    ],
    "accepts_tls_channel_id": false
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon16.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "128": "icon128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*"
  ]
}
```

**Error:**

[image]

|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message means there is no *correctly registered* listener or the extension wasn't enabled at the time the message was sent.

See [sending messages from web pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage) section:

> From your app or extension, you may listen to messages from web pages via the runtime.**onMessageExternal** or runtime.**onConnectExternal** APIs, similar to cross-extension messaging. Only the web page can initiate a connection.

So you need to replace onConnect with onConnectExternal:

```
chrome.runtime.onConnectExternal.addListener(port => {
  //
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This work!!!
I can only send via port.postMessage with background.js ? 
I can't use chrome.runtime.sendMessage?

Comment: To use sendMessage you need to add a listener for onMessageExternal, see the documentation for the exact syntax and parameters.